# Selenium vs Cypress for tests that hit databases, elasticsearch, filesystem, etc

Tags: selenium, cypress

I am getting ready to start a new automation project and have done some reading on Cypress as a Selenium alternative.  Given that Cypress apparently runs directly in the browser as opposed to Selenium's approach, is it difficult to perform test steps with Cypress tests that fall outside the browser such as communicating with a data store, interacting with services and interacting with product infrastructure such as remote file systems?  With my limited exposure to Cypress, I have only seen browser tests so I was hoping someone could shed some light on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need access to things outside the browser, I would go with selenium. This is what I currently do, I have a webdriver wrapper which has "plugins" loaded so that I can make db statements, query the webserver and additionally issue selenium commands to the browser.

If you're looking for just test 100% within the browser, then cypress may be the way to go.

Alternatively, you could use selenium for workflow tests and cypress or even [qunitjs](https://qunitjs.com/) for intra-browser unit tests.

In the app I work on, I actually ship a page which contains a qunit page with all of the in-browser tests. Then in a selenium test, in addition to the rest of the workflow, I browser to the qunit page and report on their status as well.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was thinking as well.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to automated testing for web applications, there are two main contenders: Selenium and Cypress. Both have their pros and cons, but which one is the best?

Selenium has been around for much longer than Cypress and is therefore more widely used. It is also more flexible, allowing for tests to be written in a variety of programming languages. However, Selenium can be slow and unreliable, and it is not as easy to use as Cypress.

Cypress, on the other hand, is a newer tool that is gaining popularity due to its simplicity and reliability. Cypress tests are written in JavaScript, making it easier for front-end developers to get started with automated testing. Cypress is also faster than Selenium and can run tests in parallel, making it more efficient.

So, which one should you use? It depends on your needs. If you need a more flexible tool that can be used with different programming languages, Selenium is a good choice. However, if you want a tool that is easier to use and more reliable, Cypress is the better option.